# Cloud init and custom script extension on azure VMSS

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

For some good reasons I need to have a cloud-init process and a custom script extension on a VMSS. The cloud-init process is intended to bootstrap base VM configuration such as hardening tools and son on while the custom script is meant to deploy application specific code.

My question is if I both in which sequence do they run? does the cloud-init process runs first and the custom script extension runs after?
Also, if I have multiple extension on my VMS such as the DSC extension, with custom scripts and monitoring agent. do they all run at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is if I both in which sequence do they run?

The cloud-init process will run first. Then the custom script will run after.

> Also, if I have multiple extension on my VMS such as the DSC
> extension, with custom scripts and monitoring agent. do they all run
> at the same time?

No, they will run one by one. See the [VM extensions sequence in VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-extension-sequencing).